# Is there a way to have a Google Composer without external IP ( overwritten with Cloud NAT ) but that can still be accessible by my Cloud Build?

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine, nat, google-cloud-build

I am currently working on a CICD pipeline with the GCP platform using a Cloud Build Trigger to deploy my dags file and run them in airflow. This part was working fine but recently I needed to change the external IP address of my Composer in order to have an overwritten static IP created with Cloud NAT so it can be whitelisted by external companies I'm working with and it allows my Composer VM to connect to the FTP of those companies using the SSH connection.

So now, my Cloud NAT is able to give to my Composer a static external IP and I am able to connect with the Composer VM to the FTP of my external companies BUT my Cloud Build is not working anymore.

My Cloud Build is now failing at the step :

```
composer environments run airflow --location europe-west1 trigger_dag  ...
```

With this error:

[image: Cloud Build step Error]

If I change the external IP address back to an ephemere one, my Cloud Build works perfectly but then I don't have any access to external FTP folders since I don't have my static whitelisted IP anymore.

A solution that I found was to have two different VM Instances: my Composer VM with the ephemere IP range which allows my Cloud Build to work perfectly and to deploy and run my dags in Airflow, and another one without any external IP address but overwritten with a static IP from my Cloud NAT which allows me to connect to the FTP folders with SSH.

I don't want to keep this solution since my final goal is to create a dag that automatically extracts the folders from the external FTPs and since Airflow uses the Composer VM I need something like the fusion of the 2 VM.

Sorry if it seems unclear, I can add more screens and infos if needed but I am not really a network guy so I don't know how Cloud Build connects to Airflow and everything.

Comment: The correct solution is to have your Cloud Composer private (without public IP) and to use Cloud NAT. However, Cloud Build can't access to y our Cloud Composer, yet. Indeed, there is a private alpha (I think it's in private beta now) for long long months and I don't know when it will be released publicly. You can find some information [here](https://cloud.google.com/sdk/gcloud/reference/alpha/builds/worker-pools/create). The principle is to have the Cloud Build worker in your VPC and thus to be able to access to private resources in your VPC.

Comment: Hi @VladimirSuvorov, did the previous comment help you to find a solution?

Comment: Hello @FaridShumbar ! And thanks Guillaume btw ! I have contacted Google Support in order to get the alpha version of the worker pools for my project but I am still waiting for an answer from Google. As I understood, the alpha version of this command is only available if your project is allowlisted by Google and you can only make it allowlisted by contacting them directly. Anyway I will keep this topic updated once I'll be able to create a worker pool !

Comment: Hello again ! So I managed to have a woking Cloud Build deploying my Airflow in a VPC now that the worker-pools are not in private beta. I followed this tutorial in order to create a private VPC for the worker-pool that is used by my Cloud Build and to connect it to the VPC of my composer with a VPN tunnel: [here](https://cloud.google.com/architecture/accessing-private-gke-clusters-with-cloud-build-private-pools#creating_two_networks_in_your_own_project) 
This solution works fine in production but you'll have to pay for the VPN tunnel and have 2 VPCs, I hope it will be upgraded later